# How do I set the Icon of the RemoteNotification in GeneXus 15

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I've been trying to set an icon for a RemoteNotification, but always get this error when I send it (I'm using log4net):

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
    em GeneXus.Utils.GXDbFile.PathToUrl(String path)
    em GeneXus.Programs.aenvianotificacaodispositivo.S121()
    em GeneXus.Programs.aenvianotificacaodispositivo.executePrivate()
    em GeneXus.Programs.aenvianotificacaodispositivo.execute()
```

I couldn't find any example in the wiki or in the forums. That's my code:

```
//commented also didn't work  
//&Image.FromUrl('http://www.example.com/my_app_icon.png') 
//&Image.FromUrl(app_icon_notif.Link())   
&Image.FromImage(app_icon_notif)  
&RemoteNotification.Icon = &Image  
&RemoteNotification.Message = &NotificMensagem   
&RemoteNotification.Event.Name = 'Notas'   
&RemoteNotification.Event.Execution = EventExecution.OnLauchByUser   
&Notifications.Add(&RemoteNotification)
```

What am I missing? I'm on GeneXus 15 U2 C#. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification icon is set by the `Android Notification Icon` property of the main object.

The corresponding imagen needs to follow some considerations mentioned [here](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31379,Images%20for%20Smart%20Devices%20applications)